# Using frustums properly

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm reading a book that says: `For perspective projection, avoid setting your near or far plane to zero or a negative number. Mathematically this just doesn’t work out.`

It is referring to the `near` and `far` parameters of a matrix such as this:

```
static Matrix4<T> Frustum(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T near, T far)
{
    T a = 2 * near / (right - left);
    T b = 2 * near / (top - bottom);
    T c = (right + left) / (right - left);
    T d = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    T e = - (far + near) / (far - near);
    T f = -2 * far * near / (far - near);
    Matrix4 m;
    m.x.x = a; m.x.y = 0; m.x.z = 0; m.x.w = 0;
    m.y.x = 0; m.y.y = b; m.y.z = 0; m.y.w = 0;
    m.z.x = c; m.z.y = d; m.z.z = e; m.z.w = -1;
    m.w.x = 0; m.w.y = 0; m.w.z = f; m.w.w = 1;
    return m;
}
```

Okay, I get that. But what I don't get is that the author then translates all the demo models by a z of -7, which appears on the screen fine. But if the frustum z near and far are set to 5 and 10, respectively, why is -7 on the screen? Shouldn't only objects translated to a z between 5 and 10 appear?

Comment: I imagine that the perspective is pointing in the negative z direction, so things between -5 and -10 appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the camera znear and zfar values are *distances* from the camera, not absolute numbers. They're always positive. That's how the math works.